# Sum of [Int] causes overflow

Tags: haskell

I have a function that returns `[Int]` and I would like to take the sum of the list. However, while each individual element is smaller than `maxBound::Int`, the sum is definitely larger.

A (contrived) exmple:

```
ghci> sum ([1..10000000] :: [Int])
-2004260032
```

Is there any way to force sum to accumulate into an `Integer` instead of an `Int`? Am I thinking about this wrong?

Comment: Is `sum $ map fromIntegral` an appropriate way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

sum returns the same type as its input list elements:

```
sum :: Num a => [a] -> a
```

so you need to pass it a `[Integer]` in order to return an `Integer`. If your input list is already of type `[Int]`, you can use the function:

```
sum . map fromIntegral
```

instead:

```
ghci> sum . map fromIntegral $ ([1..10000000] :: [Int])
50000005000000
```

Comment: Hahaha, I came to the same conclusion just a few seconds before you posted this. Wonderful.

Comment: I'm surprised this works, given that the type is `:: Num a => a`.  Is this GHCi's type defaulting coming in to play?

Comment: @Matt Fenwick: Yes, Integer is used by default for Num a => a.