# How is this polymorphic value dealt with when used as a value of multiple types?

Tags: haskell, polymorphism

Given this line of code (which I first saw in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12738163/894284)):

```
pVal :: Num a => a
pVal = sum . map fromIntegral $ ([1..10000000] :: [Int])
```

If it's used as multiple types, is the expression completely reevaluated for each type?  Is one result for each type kept around?

For example:

```
pInt :: Int
pInt = pVal

pDub :: Double
pDub = pVal
```

Comment: This might be a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179453/why-are-polymorphic-values-not-inferred-in-haskell.  Should I delete?

Comment: As an appendix to hammar's answer: when you're using it at a specific type in a programme, the compiler might share the value for that type between uses. In simple cases at least, GHC does that when optimisations are enabled. So if you use it at types `Int` and `Integer`, GHC will often produce specialised top-level values `pVal_s :: Integer`, `pVal_s1 :: Int` and rewrite rules to use those instead of the polymorphic `pVal`. But I don't know what the heuristics are, when it is deemed worthwhile to create a specialisation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Technically, the Haskell standard doesn't specify. In practice, it's re-evaluated each time. You can verify this yourself using `Debug.Trace`:

```
import Debug.Trace (trace)

pVal :: Num a => a
pVal = trace "evaluating..." $ sum . map fromIntegral $ ([1..10000] :: [Int])
```

Try it in GHCi:

```
> pVal :: Int
evaluating...
50005000
> pVal :: Int
evaluating...
50005000
```

However, binding this value to a concrete type will allow it to be re-used.

```
pInt :: Int
pInt = pVal
```

Notice there's no "evaluating..." the second time:

```
> pInt
evaluating...
50005000
> pInt
50005000
```